# Type 'Exercise' is not an array type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

am trying to set the bodyParts from the data am getting but am getting Type 'Exercise' is not an array type. am confuse here, please can someone help me to know what am doing wrong here

here's my code

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Exercise, ExerciseContextType } from "../@types.Exercise";
import { fetchData, exerciseOption } from "../utilities/fetchData";

const ExerciseState = React.createContext<ExerciseContextType | null>(null)

const ExerciseContext= ({children})=> {
 const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
 const [bodyParts, setBodyParts] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchExercisesData = async ():Promise<void> => {
      const bodyPartsData = await fetchData('https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList', exerciseOption);

      setBodyParts(['all', ...bodyPartsData]);
    };

    fetchExercisesData();
  }, []);

 return (
    <ExerciseState.Provider value={search, setSearch, exercises, setExercises}>
        {children}
    </ExerciseState.Provider>
 )
}

// @types.Exercise file

export interface Exercise {
    bodyPart: string
    equipment: string
    gifUrl: string
    id: string
    name: string
    target: string
  }
  export type ExerciseContextType = {
    exercise: Exercise[];
  };
```

Comment: We're missing some code here. What's the return type of `fetchData`

Comment: can you please share the response of the API that you are getting?